# Unminify a Pythlike String

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

Pyth is perhaps the most successful general-purpose golfing language. Though it is somewhat in [decline](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16561/what-happened-to-languages-like-cjam-and-pyth) as a result of newer languages, from 2014 to 2016 Pyth's concise syntax, constant updates, overloading, and (for its era) many builtins made it a favorite for the majority of questions.

Pyth code is often difficult to read. Even the output of the debug mode (transpiled Python) often consists of a long line, sometimes with parentheses nested ten deep. However, correctly formatted Pyth is very readable.

Here's a piece of Pyth code, written by @isaacg in [Play the Word Chain](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68734/39328).

```
.MlZfqhMtTeMPT+Lzs.pMyQ
```

It's much more readable like this.

```
.M                     Filter by gives-maximal-value of
   l Z                   lambda Z:length(Z) over
   f                     filter by (lambda T:
     q                     equal
       hM t T                head-map tail T
       eM P T                end-map Pop T)
     +L                    Append z to each element in
        z                        
        s .pM y Q            flattened permutations of each subset of Q
```

For this challenge, we eliminate the [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) aspect of categorizing Pyth characters and focus on formatting. Instead of being Pyth code, the input will consist of characters in `0123456789M`. The digit `n` represents a function of arity `n`, and `M` represents an operator. For example, the above code is represented as `210221M101M102M011M10`. Here are the steps to unminify:

#### Separate the string into tokens.

A token matches `[0-9]M*`. `0M` will not occur in input.

#### Add trailing 0s.

When there are not enough arguments, Pyth appends as many implicit variables (lambda variables or `Q`s) to the code as are necessary to fill the arguments of the program; these should be represented by `0`s.

#### Group tokens into lines.

The arity of a token is the value of its digit.

- An arity-0 token (i.e. a 0) ends a line.
- For an arity-1 token the next token should go on the same line, separated by a space.
- For an arity >=2 token, its arguments go on separate lines, in the order they appear in the code, each followed by their own subarguments and so on. Arguments to a token are indented to the end of that token plus one space.

### Input

A nonempty string (or char array, array of length-1 strings, etc. as allowed by Standard I/O Methods) consisting of `0123456789M`, which will not contain the substring `0M`.

### Output

The string formatted according to the above rules.

### Test cases

```
210221M101M102M011M10

2
  1 0
  2
    2
      1M 1 0
      1M 1 0
    2M
       0
       1 1M 1 0


123M4M

1 2
    3M
       4M
          0
          0
          0
          0
       0
       0
    0


2MM

2MM
    0
    0


11011100

1 1 0
1 1 1 0
0


9000000

9
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
```

Comment: *Related question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47798/a-basic-pyth-like-syntax-checker*

Comment: Can I take the input as an array of digits/string? Example `210221M101M102M011M10` would be `[2,1,0,2,2,1,'M',1,0,1,'M',1,0,2,'M',0,1,1,'M',1,0]`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz No, unless standard I/O rules require that you be allowed to (which I don't think they do.) IMO it would slightly change the challenge if the `M`s are allowed to be a different datatype from the integers.

Comment: @lirtosiast So an array of characters/single-character strings is fine, just not using different datatypes between digits and `M`?

Comment: @KamilDrakari Indeed.

Comment: What's the rule for the grammar of `M`?

Comment: @LeakyNun an M is always part of the preceding token, and doesn't change its arity.

Comment: What is the empty string to output?

Comment: @LeakyNun Empty string is now undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't understand, how many trailing `0`s are added?

Comment: @Kyky As many as are required to fill missing arguments. An arity-k token requires k arguments and each token fills an argument. So if the end of your program has e.g. n 3s in a row, you need 2n 0s at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>192</s> <s>190</s> 187 bytes

```hs
unlines.snd.f
f(n:r)|(m,t)<-span(>'9')r,(s,l)<-n#t=(s,n?((n:m):map((' '<$(n:n:m))++)l))
f e=(e,["0"])
'1'?(a:b:r)=(a++drop(length a)b):r
_?s=s
'0'#s=(s,[])
n#s|(r,l)<-f s=(l++)<$>pred n#r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1Na8MwDIbv/hWmCVgiabFzW4ibw86FHgfdGG5jt2GOFmzv1t8@z9lBSHp4Px4mflnv82Jm4prPlGwwt8Rr/p5/yM9k4yHSdHDMAfUBn7C0CYd9XA3BUbwIDC3E1hdEVdLlpBGKcsF@MSuA4GKoy78RbBr0iMxxq8G2l53cfSATSoxg@msJ12CaZgrfK3hL9/TgBq/YB/Y5Rh2ZkKKKW8OluKiKTwj/vY4X6kv2UB/XYCdOVci5U7Lr1EnJbbqTVNv@vTlv7jHv317P5z8)

There has to be a better way to handle the arity-1 case, it currently takes up 45 bytes.

**Edits:**

- -2 bytes by switching to a different method of handling 1, though the previous method has probably more optimization potential.
- -3 bytes by not converting the character digits to numbers and using `pred` instead of `n-1`.

```hs
unlines.snd.f
f(n:r)|(m,t)<-span(>'9')r,(s,l)<-read[n]#t,w<-map((' '<$(n:n:m))++)=(s,last$((n:m):w l):[(n:m++' ':h):w t|n<'2',h:t<-[l]])
f e=(e,["0"])
0#s=(s,[])
n#s|(r,l)<-f s=(l++)<$>(n-1)#r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1Bi8MgEIXv/RXSBByJFs1txfSy50KPC24O0ppNWDMUtfSS396s7mGYNx9v3ptd@vUh7KtbkAxkweyju2XSku/9iWFBn04J76fpMAHqyDZYeWZGpIdDONMPyiKHxENB0bu7xbHJ/GXE6h4AlFDTljfUK2Ndx4bqdCm3ABXpFwlM26q7rnj1XFHe0NCe8llnI2wYR3aYiB/Ac3uUx3LJJtUgWyQ2aYP43z6RQkMpMe0ZUCjWxH3vlex7dVGyTn@Rqu73bQruJ@3i6/N6/QM)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>160</s> 159 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,a=[d=0,p=[1]])=>s.replace(/(.)M*/g,(s,c)=>(g=_=>a[d]?s+(P=p[d]-=c--&&~s.length,c?`
`.padEnd(P):' '):g(d--))(a[d]--,a[++d]=+c,p[d]=p[d-1]))+(d?f('0',a):'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU49a8MwEN3zK0SG6K6WHEvp0hQlU5aC20BHYxIhyW6Ka4vIFLL0r7tSu5X64HHHvY@7d/2pg7le/Mj7wbppahQEplVlVcG8qkRdo9qF/Op8p42DNeRY3q1bFlUmMtCqk9rpytb7kMFR@ThxZThfrb5C3rm@Hd@Y2Z8X59xre@gtHHFLCcVtC5ZzREhezpmusszWKjMsRaQcLmrEDOy@AVpQpqOP4hScJ4pQTtNLTo@wkfi4MEMfhs7l3dBCA0spCilFKYoEWRYi9SWSjEQ7/lULuSnvy1lalvOciCci5rMfip/6n6eHDz/eSBivl77dEho1T68vz/nv4tLcUsISEadv)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                          // f = recursive function taking:
  s,                           //   s   = input string
  a = [                        //   a[] = array holding the number of expected arguments
    d = 0,                     //   d   = current depth, initialized to 0
    p = [1]                    //   p[] = array holding the padding values
  ]                            //
) =>                           //
  s.replace(                   // search in s all substrings
    RegExp('(.)M*', 'g'),      // consisting of a digit followed by 0 to N 'M' characters
    (s, c) =>                  // for each substring s beginning with the digit c:
      ( g = _ =>               //   g = recursive function
          a[d] ?               //     if we're still expecting at least one argument at
                               //     this depth:
            s + (              //       append s
              P = p[d] -=      //       update the padding value P = p[d] for this depth:
                c-- &&         //         decrement c; unless c was equal to 0,
                ~s.length,     //         add the length of s + 1 to p[d]
              c ?              //       if c is not equal to 0 (i.e. was not equal to 1):
                `\n`.padEnd(P) //         append a linefeed followed by P - 1 spaces
              :                //       else:
                ' '            //         append a single space
            )                  //
          :                    //     else (all arguments have been processed):
            g(d--)             //       decrement the depth and call g again
      )(                       //   before the initial call to g:
        a[d]--,                //     decrement the number of arguments at depth d
        a[++d] = +c,           //     set the number of arguments for the next depth
        p[d] = p[d - 1]        //     set the padding value for the next depth,
      )                        //     using a copy of the previous depth
  ) + (                        // end of replace()
    d ?                        // if we're not back at depth 0:
      f('0', a)                //   do a recursive call to f with an extra '0'
    :                          // else:
      ''                       //   stop recursion
  )                            //
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 75 bytes

```
ＦＳ⊞υ⎇⁼ιM⁺⊟υιι≔⮌υυ≔⟦⟧θ≔⟦⟧ηＷ∨υη«≔⎇υ⊟υ0ιι¿⊖Σι↘→⊞θι⊞ηΣιＷ∧η¬§η±¹«⊟ηＭ⊕Ｌ⊟θ←¿η⊞η⊖⊟η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBNa4QwED3rrwieRrCgHndPwvYgrK3s9lZ6EB1NwI1rPtyWsr/dJiF228CQvDcf701a2oh2asZ17SdBoORXrc5KMD5AHJNaSwo6IW8oeCO@4HnWzSiBJSSqojgh9agl1NMVtAHMRbwPCynZwOGECwqJLqcf9PtHQub/kBp4o2xEAq/C6lGj/R0GvmRTN4lNK0ojp7YPg9qYVeCerCdwwFbgBbnCDs76YhIxqaYFYXeYbvzEBqpsKY4SPf/LuW3nbawFNCF@hmG8w4J3ln@ZFBSq5B1@OohDoxCy2B7r3fuyhqlrD5xayR/2jsgHRV3JbLoSsjti75y4Taj/fzP971J@oi27h/d1zbM0z7MqS23kVZqZe31axuYH) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＳ⊞υ⎇⁼ιM⁺⊟υιι
```

Loop over the input characters and turn them into a list of digits with optional `M` suffixes.

```
≔⮌υυ
```

Reverse this list so that we can use `Pop` to consume it.

```
≔⟦⟧θ
```

This variable is a stack of tokens whose arity has not yet been fulfilled.

```
≔⟦⟧η
```

This variable is a stack of the remaining arity of the unfulfilled tokens.

```
Ｗ∨υη«
```

Repeat until we have consumed all of the tokens and emptied the stack.

```
     ≔⎇υ⊟υ0ι
```

Get the next token or `0` if none.

```
     ι¿⊖Σι↘→
```

Print the token and then move the cursor horizontally if it begins with `1` otherwise diagonally.

```
     ⊞θι⊞ηΣι
```

Add the token and its arity to the appropriate variables.

```
     Ｗ∧η¬§η±¹«
```

Repeat while the arity stack is nonempty but the top arity is zero.

```
              ⊟η
```

Discard the zero arity.

```
              Ｍ⊕Ｌ⊟θ←
```

Remove its token and move that many characters left.

```
              ¿η⊞η⊖⊟η
```

If there are any arities left then decrement the top arity.